# Google Visualization-Invalid row type for row 0

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I have to visualize url json data on a pie chart with google visualization. My code seems to be as it has to be for the purpose, but I am getting an 'Invalid row type for row 0' error in the console. Is there any problem with the format of the data? If there is anyone that could help, that would be much appreciated. Here is my code:

PHP:

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents('http://data.police.uk/api/crimes-street/all-crime?lat=52.629729&lng=-1.131592&date=2013-01'); 
    $json = str_replace("\xe2\x80\xa8", '\\u2028', $json);
    $json = str_replace("\xe2\x80\xa9", '\\u2029', $json);
    echo $json;
?>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

// Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
      url: "getData.php",
      dataType:"json",
      async: false
      }).responseText;

  //Create an array of the JSON data and then create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
  var array = JSON.parse(jsonData);
  var dataTableData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(array);
  var table = google.visualization.DataTable(dataTableData);

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240});
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The JSON does not represent data which can be transformed to a **2-dimensional array** `google.visualization.DataTable` can simply not interpret this. Each item contains complex subitems like `location` and `outcome_status`.
2. You **must** include columns - [**arrayToDataTable is very specific about that**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google.visualization.arraytodatatable).
3. The most important : How on earth do you imagine those data to be presented as a piechart? There is only one specfic number-field at first level, `location_subtype`. You cannot produce a piechart based on various strings.

But, you can sanitize the data and show them as a `google.visualization.Table` :

First create a DataTable with some columns :

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('string','category');
dataTable.addColumn('string','context');
dataTable.addColumn('string','id');
dataTable.addColumn('number','location_subtype');
dataTable.addColumn('string','location_type');
dataTable.addColumn('string','month');
dataTable.addColumn('string','persistent_id');
```

convert your jsonData to JSON

```
var json=JSON.parse(jsonData);
```

sanitize and insert the data. Here I just delete the `location` and `outcome_status` subitems, but you may want to extract values from those subitems instead and insert them as columns in the `dataTable` :

```
for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
   delete json[i].location;
   delete json[i].outcome_status;
   var row = [];        
   for (var item in json[i]) {
     row.push(json[i][item]);
   }        
   dataTable.addRow(row);
}
```

finally create the Table() :

```
var chart = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(dataTable, {width: 1000, height: 300});
```

the result will look like this :

[image]

---

**update**

```
var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
dataTable.addColumn('string','category');
dataTable.addColumn('string','context');
dataTable.addColumn('number','id');
dataTable.addColumn('string','location_subtype');
dataTable.addColumn('string','location_type');
dataTable.addColumn('string','month');
dataTable.addColumn('string','persistent_id');
dataTable.addColumn('string','street name');
dataTable.addColumn('string','outcome status');

json=JSON.parse(jsonData);

for (var i=0;i<json.length;i++) {
    var row = [];       
    row.push(json[i].category);
    row.push(json[i].context);
    row.push(json[i].id);
    row.push(json[i].location_subtype);
    row.push(json[i].location_type);
    row.push(json[i].month);
    row.push(json[i].persistent_id);
    row.push(json[i].location.street.name);
    row.push(json[i].outcome_status ? json[i].outcome_status.category : "null");
    dataTable.addRow(row);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Definetely helpful! Trying to get the pie chart working now. Thanks again

Comment: @AndreUk13, gr8 :) yes, if you take some of the values from the subitems, I think you easily can produce a meaningfull piechart. Happy programming!

Comment: Tried to parse the nested data in json (specifically the location and the outcome_status) and output them on a table without success. I don't know if it's because the format of the data is bad for Google Visualization. Actually, I'm getting the  Row given with size different than 2 (the number of columns in the table).

Comment: which fields exactly (in location / outcome_status) are you trying to extract? There are nested subitems inside too (street). As Table strings for all columns is ok, quote fields there the strings is not quoted - could imagine it fails on  null-values (?) Do you have a list of the fields you want? Maybe I can make an example.

Comment: I;m trying to get the street name and the outcome_status. My code looks like: `var obj1 = array[i].location.street.name;
  var obj2 = array[i].outcome_status;
  pushedData.push(obj1);
  pushedData.push(obj2);
  alert(obj1);
  alert(obj2);
  
   for (var item in pushedData[i]) {
    if(array[i].location.street.name == null){
     row.push(pushedData[i][item]);
    }
   }
   dataTable.addRow(row); 
 }`

Comment: see update, the above gives a table with the fields mentioned in the correct order

Comment: I got it working but with 2 loops. I'm keeping your, as it is more optimized. Thanks once again. You have some good examples as well at your fiddles. Cheers :)

Comment: TRAILING COMMA!!! as i like to add any time i get time to... I came across the same error ONLY with IE8... So, did a google and came to this... But the only thing that made me look at my code was the mention of   arrayToDataTable.. Anyway, i had a trailing comma in the array that i forgot to remove after deleting the last row...... So just keep this in mind anyone if the above is ruled out.

Comment: hey @Mayhem, I dont quite follow - where do you see a trailing comma? I know the issue with old IE's though :)